# How to get int value from snapshot child in Firebase Javascript trigger function

Tags: javascript, function, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I created the onCreate function for node teams. It counts a number of players in a team. It works well. Here is the code:

```
exports.onPlayerToTeamAdd = functions.database.ref('/teams/{teamId}/players/{playerId}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const count = snapshot.ref.parent.parent.child('count_players');

    return count.transaction(count => {
        return count + 1;
    });
});
```

Here is the onDelete function:

```
exports.onPlayerFromTeamDelete = functions.database.ref('/teams/{teamId}/players/{playerId}')
.onDelete((snapshot, context) => {
    const count = snapshot.ref.parent.parent.child('count_players');

    return count.transaction(count => {
        return count - 1;
    });             
});
```

The onDelete function works well until the delete of the whole team. When I delete the team, it creates the node of the same team with 'count_players' with value -x (x is number of players in team before).

My question is: how can I handle the state of deleting the whole team? Thank you very much.

Comment: If you created the Cloud Function when the team was still empty, then adding X players, and then deleting all of them, should leave you with a count of `0`. Does that not happen for you? Or did you attach the function after the team already had members?